# How to save settings in application directory?

Tags: c#, windows

I use the inbuilt `Properties.Settings.Default` to  save and load settings for my appliction.
However, by default the settings file (when Properties.Settings.Default.save() is called) is saved in the  user's directory (Something like users/bob/appdata/documents/..).

I want the settings file to be saved in the program's root directory instead. (So let's say d:/myapp) So when the user for example copies the folder with the application to a different computer, the settings file will be carried as well, since it's saved in the application's folder.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Usually not a great idea as you will often find in a production environment users wont have rights to save there.

Comment: If i detect the inability to write in the app folder then i will just fold back to the default user folder.

Comment: if application is launched by user (not admin), the application can't write in standard folder of the application (program files).

Comment: Xaruth: My application is portable, it doesn't install. So i know the user has writing rights, since he had to copy the app folder there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding for a commercial environment, a large portion of that market use roaming profiles that replicate to the local machine whenever a user logs on to a new computer. This includes user.config files stored in the Roaming folder of the Windows profile for a user.

You can set `Settings` files to target the Roaming Windows profile when you change an entry in the `Settings` file to `User`, the option to set `Roaming` to `true` in the Properties box for that setting entry in the `Settings` Designer in Visual Studio.

I would strongly recommend you do not attempt to write to the application's main file as from experience, I have not yet come across a corporate environment where user's are allowed to change their application installation folders themselves as this presents a massive security risk.

The obvious exception being if you are writing this for network administrator personnel but even then, do so with caution.

Otherwise, don't do it - it's bad practice.